# Copy a range of cells from one table to another, using the remote function

Tags: reference, spreadsheet, org-mode

Being aware of the `$$#` and `@@#` syntax, what if I want to copy a range of cells from a table to another one, not full rows or full columns, using the remote function?

I wanted to copy the rows from the third column of the source table to the second column of the target table. My workaround was to add an empty column to the target table, and apply the following.
`#+TBLFM: @<<$<<<..@>>$>>=remote($1, @>$$#)`
Is there any way to add an offset to the `$#` reference, e.g. `+1` or `-1`?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer in another post, "although it's not pretty":
https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/47444/org-mode-copy-cells-from-a-remote-org-table-with-shifted-columns